# php_zip.dll on start can't be found on start

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, php-extension, php-ziparchive

I'm trying to install php_zip for a laravel project. I'm using Windows.

I then put this `php_zip.dll` inside my php/ext folder.
[image]

I then edited my php.ini file to add this line :

```
extension=zip
```

to add zip among the existing extensions.

Still PHP tells me this when i deploy my server :

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\zip (the specified module was not found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zip.dll (the specified module was not found)) in Unknown on line 0
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Mon Jan 25 11:50:11 2021] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\zip (the specified module was not found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zip.dll (the specified module was not found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

As we can see PHP is trying to read the proper folder and is looking for the proper file. Why is it unable to load it then ?

Comment: restart your server

Comment: The right declaration is : `extension=php_extname.dll` so in your case `extension=php_zip.dll`, then restart apache/nginx server

Comment: Yeah i tried all possible forms of the statement. The strangest part is when i follow the console link (C:\xampp\php\ext\php_zip.dll) and vscode can even open it without problem while the terminal says it can't

Comment: @raphael.oester it mean is your `.dll` is not compatible with your php version  download another one

Comment: Right... I'm running PHP 8.0.1 and the latest php_zip version is for 7.5. I have absolutely no idea how i'm going to open that zip file now

Comment: There's no PHP 7.5 , what's bundled with PHP is meant to work, just make sure you're using the php_zip.dll that came with PHP and not mix and match with older versions. Also make sure the path is correct. It currently looks for extensions in directory `C:\xampp\php\ext` but this may not be the right place if e.g. you have multiple PHP versions installed

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php No reference to version 8.x, but, can you check if your version is compiled with the right option?

Answer (score 1):

SO after php version 7.4, you must go to apache, and select `php.ini`
after you must find `extension=zip` and delete the `;` before `extension=zip`
then save the config and restart your server php...and it ll be ok